# VBA not looping filtered rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have this big excel file that is automated to do some processes. Today, I figured there is an issue with one of the columns and I need to fix it. to fix it I am generated this code below to filter column N to show all '#N/A'. with the filtered rows, I want to check and see if the offset to the right 2 columns has the value "Available". if it does, I want to loop through all column N and replace the '#N/A' with 'Unkown'. but the code I generated only works for the first filtered cell and doesn't loop.

```
Sub tess()
ActiveSheet.Range("$C$1:$AR$468").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="#N/A"

ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(, 12).Select

Dim lr
lr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.CountLarge

For Each cell In Range("n1:n" & lr)
If ActiveCell.Value = CVErr(xlErrNA) And ActiveCell.Offset(, 2).Value = "Available" Then

  ActiveCell.Value = "Unkown Person"

  End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can avoid looping by adding another filter:

```
Sub tess()
    With ActiveSheet.Range("$C$1:$AR$468")
        .AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="#N/A"
        .AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="Available"
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Columns(12)) > 1 Then .Offset(1, 11).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "Unkown Person"
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect, it works. thank you. any reason why mine didn't work?

Comment: It’s because of what Excel Developers explained in his answer: you looped through a range of cells by means of “cell” iterator variable but inside the loop you were using “ActiveCell”, which however was keeping referencing the same cell (the one activated by the Select before the loop)

Answer (score 1):

You should refer to "cell" within your For loop, not "ActiveCell".